# php: how to replace all string values by variables values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, replace

I am using that kind of html template:

```
Hello {{username}}, my email is {{email}} and my age is {{age}}
```

(number of {{variables}} is dynamic)

I would like to autoamtically parse the template and replace all {{variables}} by their php variable content

ex:

```
$username="Peter"; $email="myemail";$age=20;
```

so it should render like :

```
$res = render("template.html", array("username"=>$username, email=>$email, age=>$age));
```

Hello Peter; my email is myemail and my age is 20

Comment: Have you considered using something like Twig instead of reinventing the wheel? ;)

Comment: This task would be solved much easier and more elegant by means of a `HEREDOC` definition, but the syntax for your template would have to be slighty different: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: how about using `<?=$username?>` instead of `{{username}}` ?

Comment: you can consider replacing all '{{' with '$' and '}}' with ''.
If you are using vim editor try this:
:%s/{{/$/gc
:%s/}}//gc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function render($template, $vars) {
    $template = file_get_contents($template);
    $search  = [];
    $replace = [];
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        $search[] = '{{'.$key.'}}';
        $replace[] = $value;
    }
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $template);
}
```

Although if you want more complexity you should use something like Handlebars:

https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy

https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function render($template,$values){
    $data=file_get_contents('templates/'.$templates); //templates/ is just templates path. you can change it.

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $data=str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $value, $data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```